# Find the last element in a group of divs before it wraps and add another DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**The requirement:**
I have a group of boxes connected with a line, the group of boxes wrap to another row according to the changing viewport. The requirement is that, an arrow pointing downwards needs to be added to the last element of the first row and an arrow pointing upwards needs to be added to the first element of the second row to show that the list has been continued from above. Please refer to the image below

[image]

**The problem:**
The problem is that I am not sure about any such selector which selects the last element before it wraps and first element after it wraps. Also, last element before it wraps changes with changing viewport size.

**Possible approach**
One approach could be - Based on width for each box and the total width defined for the whole list and view port width, calculate how many elements fit in one row and select the appropriate element with nth-Child selector

However, the above approach can be messy and hard to maintain. Is there a better solution to it ?

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you are not deterred by the "cost" of having a script run on a window resize event, then you can do this relatively easy, by looping over these elements, and checking where the `offsetTop` changes between two elements.

Comment: To add on @CBroe. An alternative to the `resize` event would be the [Resize Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API) with which you can observe the changing of dimensions of a single element.

Comment: A better solution might be to go see the UI designer and find a feasible compromise, like simply continuing the line on the right instead of an arrow. (:

Comment: Simple example using a primitive resize handler, can be made a more sophisticated using what @EmielZuurbier mentioned: https://jsfiddle.net/69hneofy/